# Get the latest date in UNIX

Tags: date, unix, unixodbc

I have data like this:

```
Code Date(YYYYDDMM)
VNM 20141202  
VNM 20141203 
VNM 20141204 
BHR 20141203 
BHR 20141204 
RUS 20150312
RUS 20142312
```

Now I want to select the `VNM` which is having latest date using UNIX command.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `awk` to convert the dates into timestamp, then compare them with `sort` and finally print the first column from the biggest one:

```
awk 'NR>1{y=substr($2,0,4)
          d=substr($2,5,2)
          m=substr($2,7,2)
          date=sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0",y,m,d)
          print $1, mktime(date)}' a |\
sort -k2 -n |\
awk 'END {print $1}'
```

Note the current dates are in the YYYYDDMM format, that's why I have to reverse them to call [`mktime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html).

#### Test step by step

```
$ awk 'NR>1{y=substr($2,0,4); d=substr($2,5,2); m=substr($2,7,2); date=sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0",y,m,d); print $1, mktime(date)}' a
VNM 1392159600
VNM 1394578800
VNM 1397253600
BHR 1394578800
BHR 1397253600
RUS 1449097200
RUS 1419289200
$ awk 'NR>1{y=substr($2,0,4); d=substr($2,5,2); m=substr($2,7,2); date=sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0",y,m,d); print $1, mktime(date)}' a | sort -k2 -n 
VNM 1392159600
BHR 1394578800
VNM 1394578800
BHR 1397253600
VNM 1397253600
RUS 1419289200
RUS 1449097200
$ awk 'NR>1{y=substr($2,0,4); d=substr($2,5,2); m=substr($2,7,2); date=sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0",y,m,d); print $1, mktime(date)}' a | sort -k2 -n | awk 'END {print $1}'
RUS
```